# Apache2 VirtualHost subdomains not working?

Tags: apache2, subdomain

I have a static public IP and I am hosting my websites on it (Ubuntu Server 12.04). I need to set up a subdomain but It's not working, even www. is not working. I bought the domain from GoDaddy and I set up the correct NS

I saved the configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` under domain.me and then I did `a2ensite domain.me` and reloaded and restarted apache2, but still no luck.

This is my configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.me
  ServerName  domain.me
  ServerAlias www.domain.me
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.me
  ServerName  me.subdomain.me
  ServerAlias www.me.subdomain.me
  DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

`curl http://domain.me` outputs the index file, `curl http://www.domain.me` outputs `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.domain.me'` and same for the subdomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it, and for those of you who is having the same problem, make sure you set up the A records